# My ajax post will not stop running (C#,JQuery,Ajax)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

My Ajax call works. It sends data to the database as expected. 
However, after it completes this task, it will not call the success or fail function. It just keeps running. I set the timeout for the ajax call but it didn't work.

I have a form in my html page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="signupForm" role="form" method="post" name="signupForm" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="TextBoxUsername">Username:</label>
       <div class="col-xs-9"><input type="text" placeholder="username" id="TextBoxUsername" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="TextBoxPassword">Password:</label>
       <div class="col-xs-9"><input type="text" placeholder="password" id="TextBoxPassword" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-xs-offset-5 control-label" for="selectImage" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">Choose Your Avatar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        // I used the Image-Picker jQuery plugin here to create a selection of images and show them as thumbnails
        <select name="selectImage" class="image-picker" id="selectImage" form="signupForm">
           <option class="grid-item" data-img-src="img1.png" value="img1.png">Image 1</option>
           <option class="grid-item" data-img-src="img2.png" value="img2.png">Image 2</option>
           <option class="grid-item" data-img-src="img3.png" value="img3.png">Image 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
// this is my main jQuery function
$(function () {
   // this is my form submit function
   $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this stops the form from refreshing the page
        create();
   });
});

// this function creates an object to be added to the database
function create() {
   user = new Object();
   user.Username = $("#TextBoxUsername").val();
   user.Password = $("#TextBoxPassword").val();

   // here I am getting the value of the selected item from <select> div
   selectedImage = document.signupForm.selectImage.options[document.signupForm.selectImage.selectedIndex].value;

   // this is just to convert the image to base 64 string.
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = selectedImage;
   // draw canvas
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
   var imageURL = canvas.toDataURL();
   user.Image = imageURL;
   // end base 64 string conversion

   $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: "api/signup", // this url goes to a controller, it works perfectly
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      processData: true,
      timeout: 3000, // does not do anything!
      success: function () {
        // this function is not being called!
        $("#lblstatus").text("User was created!");
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // this function is not being called either!
        errorRoutine(jqXHR);
    }
   });

}; // end create function
```

Like I said, the database is receiving the data just fine. But for some reason, this ajax call will not stop running. If I manually stop the application from the debugger, I can check the database and everything worked. I just need this ajax call to complete.

Comment: are there any errors in console in browser? What happens when you place a debugger; in the success and error  function of Ajax? Do they get called?

Comment: even when a debugger is placed in those functions, they are not called.

Comment: How does your code work when you haven't defined the 'data' variable in JSON.stringify(data)? - Change you button type to button instead of submit and then check your code.

Comment: Tryed to replicate on jsfiddle. There is a lot wrong with your code,<div class="form-group>

Comment: these are just typos. I will fix them. I'm new to stackoverflow and transferring my code to this page was tedious. thanks for the input though

Comment: it was also 3 in the morning when I posted this. but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the type to button and set an id to it `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submitbtn" >Sign in</button>` And handle it by jquery click function `$("#submitbtn").click(function () {
        create();
   });`

by that, the page will not refresh even if you don't have the e.preventDefault();

since your using an ajax, the form is not needed anyway. So it can work even if you don't have a `form` tag

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with the Image-Picker plugin?

Comment: Can I see your code? Maybe your just missing something. { <div class="form-group>} you forgot the "

Comment: thanks I got it working, it was a stupid type in my html form. Next time I will post more complete code on stackoverflow to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I found the tiny typo culprit.

it was inside the success function. I didn't add the "#" in front of "("lblstatus"). It should have been ("#lblstatus").

silly silly mistake.

Thanks for all the suggestions. It turned out to be a typo afterall.